# Add a number to every element in an Array[Double]

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
var x = some array Array[Double]
val n = 3
```

I want to add n to every element in x, how? I tried:

```
x.map(v => v + n)
```

But that doesnt work.

Comment: "doesnt work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: `x.map(v => v + n)` is *exactly* the way to do what you want, so if that "doesnt work", then there must be something else that is wrong that you are not showing us.

Comment: Relax lol, I would have updated my question if you just asked to elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a third var like this :

```
val x2 = x.map(_ + n)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to construct a new `Array` but just want to modify the values in the existing one, then:

```
for (i <- x.indices)
  x(i) += n
```

In general, the Scala collections API doesn't currently offer higher-level operations that do in-place mutation, so you have to resort to lower-level code like this. (That will change in Scala 2.13.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the return output of map into a variable to get the updated array.